# Set media query dynamically in Tailwind css

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In my react js application i have a component where i want to set the mobile break pint according to a variable:

```
<Component size={'500px'}/>

const Component = ({size}) => {
 return (
   <div md:flex>hello</div>
) 
}
```

I want to add instead of `md:flex` something like `[size]:flex` to be able to set break point according to that props.(ex: set display flex if the size is 500px or 100px or 900px) 
 Question: Is there possible to set the mediaquery according to the way that i described above?

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you can update the config file of tailwind to have whatever breakpoint / names you want https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens

Comment: @offoffoff Yes, but I need to set the break point for this component following the size prop. Could you help?

Comment: In theory you can use something like `[@media_screen_and_(min-width:500px)]:flex`. However you have to [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) every possible size variations as it will be dynamic [classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka, could you please send me the link where is explained this adnotation?

Comment: @Asking [sure](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) npm package:

```
const rootClassName = cn(
     // you can add any tailwind classNames first
     "h-full flex flex-col",
     // this is conditional part. based on size prop, define className
    {
      [md:flex-1]: size === "A",
      [sm:flex-1]: size === "B",
    }
  )
```

Comment: it should look like this: `<div className={classNames('',  {['md:bg-[red]']: b === 500})}>testing</div>`? Because it does not work. Could you help?

Comment: there is an issue because if `size` will be `500` for example, then `[md:flex-1]: size === "A",` will fork anyway for `md` size event the `md` and `size` are different. In my case i need to add `flex-1` only if size is 500, so i need  to set the breakpoint dynamicly. Could you help?